# DateTime in C# winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Actually I am working with .CSV file. I have taken all data of .CSV file into DataTable.
code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Revision1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable datable = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Select .CSV ffile";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            txtboxpath.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }

        private void operatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = txtboxpath.Text;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] value = line.Split(',');

            DataRow row;
            foreach (string dc in value)
            {
                datable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                if (value.Length == datable.Columns.Count)
                {
                    row = datable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = value;
                    datable.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }




        }

        private void generatecsvbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Till now everything is fine.
The google drive link of .CSV file [click for.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OeuBkkbd2xcSNs4JKNH_ErXr1Hpb1ot/view?usp=sharing)

Now I am checking the below condition which is also inside operatebtn_Click method after last while loop:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datable.Rows[0][1].ToString(),"dd-MM-yy HH:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = dt.ToString();
string s1 = datable.Rows[0][1].ToString();
if(s==s1)
{
                //code here
}
```

But the condition is giving false value. How I modify my code so that the condition will be true?
When I am debugging through breakpoint I am getting the following value:

```
dt = 11/30/2017 10:00:00 AM
s = 30-NOV-2017 10:00:00 AM
s1 = 30-11-2017 10:00
```

Comment: Did you know there are specialized libraries for parsing CSV files, like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: No, I was not aware of that

Comment: It makes working with them much easier and safer with dates, decimals etc.

Comment: Okay, I am checking out the library

Comment: I have no idea how to work with this library.

Comment: Well fortunately for you, the library has documentation that will give you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the CSV file or the datatable.

You are parsing a `string` with an exact specific format into a `DateTime`. You are then converting that `DateTime` back to a `string` but with no specific format info, so the conversion uses the default format of the culture to format the `DateTime` to a `string`.

If you want to get the same result, use the [same format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) when calling [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string s = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:ss");
```

Comment: I´m quite sure you want to say: string s = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");

Comment: @nabuchodonossor That makes more sense but the format was copy pasted from the op.

Comment: Yes, now I saw it!

Answer (score 1):

You should convert all the strings to be compared to `DateTimes` and compare those. After all you want to compare dates, not texts. The `DateTime` structure itself does not store the dates as formatted and is therefore neutral in this respect. According to the original documentation

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar) [...]